How to combine canonical AND alternate correctly to declare same page language variations?
Am I combining canonical and alternate correctly here, to declare (and satisfy search engines of) same page language variations?
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="canonical"   href="https://example.com/nl/projectid">
    <link rel="alternate"   href="https://example.com/nl/projectid" hreflang="nl" >
    <link rel="alternate"   href="https://example.com/en/projectid" hreflang="en">
</meta>

Please refrain from discussions. Only answer if you know the right answer or have useful suggestions. Thank you.
